# How do I structure this transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

We have an ASP.NET/MSSQL based web app which generates orders with sequential order numbers.

When a user saves a form, a new order is created as follows:

1. SELECT MAX(order_number) FROM order_table, call this max_order_number
2. set new_order_number = max_order_number + 1
3. INSERT a new order record, with this new_order_number (it's just a field in the order record, not a database key)

If I enclose the above 3 steps in single transaction, will it avoid duplicate order numbers from being created, if two customers save a new order at the same time? (And let's say the system is eventually on a web farm with multiple IIS servers and one MSSQL server).

I want to avoid two customers selecting the same MAX(order_number) due to concurrency somewhere in the system.

What isolation level should be used? Thank you.

Comment: An identity column, as mentioned below, would be the best solution. However, you are allowed only one identity column per table. If you already have another column as identity, then you could consider making order_number just be some composite of that identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an identity is by far the best idea.  I create all my tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    mytable_id int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
    name varchar(50)
)
```

The "identity" flag means, "Let SQL Server assign this number for me".  The (1, 1) means that identity numbers should start at 1 and be incremented by 1 each time someone inserts a record into the table.  Not Null means that nobody should be allowed to insert a null into this column, and "primary key" means that we should create a [clustered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on this column.  With this kind of a table, you can then insert your record like this:

```
-- We don't need to insert into mytable_id column; SQL Server does it for us!
INSERT INTO mytable (name) VALUES ('Bob Roberts')
```

But to answer your literal question, I can give a lesson about how transactions work.  It's certainly possible, although not optimal, to do this:

```
-- Begin a transaction - this means everything within this region will be 
-- executed atomically, meaning that nothing else can interfere.
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    DECLARE @id bigint

    -- Retrieves the maximum order number from the table
    SELECT @id = MAX(order_number) FROM order_table

    -- While you are in this transaction, no other queries can change the order table,
    -- so this insert statement is guaranteed to succeed
    INSERT INTO order_table (order_number) VALUES (@id + 1)

-- Committing the transaction releases your lock and allows other programs 
-- to work on the order table
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Just keep in mind that declaring your table with an identity primary key column does this all for you automatically.

Comment: Your transaction example is exactly what I wanted to confirm, whether the SELECT and INSERT would run atomically together with the default settings or if I had to specify a particular isolation level. About identity fields, we do use them a lot (I think of them as "autonumber", betraying my MySQL background) already but this order number has to add to an existing sequence. I wonder if it is possible to change the IDENTITY field's starting point.

Comment: Yes, you can use IDENTITY(1234, 1) - meaning "start at 1234" and "increment by one".

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) as the order number?

**Edit:**
As far as I know, you can make the current order_number column an Identity (you may have to reset the seed, it's been a while since I've done this). You might want to do some tests.
[Here's](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/) a good read about what actually goes on when you change a column to an Identity in SSMS. The author mentions how this may take a while if the table already has millions of rows.

Comment: Updated in response to "IDENTITY" suggestions:
This system has to maintain backwards compability with a legacy system from which thousands of order numbers are already imported and these order numbers go to other suppliers where they are scanned by barcode, etc. So we must continue the existing order sequence once our new system goes live. Could the IDENTITY approach be modified to fit this scenario?

Comment: You can create you identity field and then 'reseed' it: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/can-i-start-identity-values-at-a-new-seed.html

Comment: Ah,both approaches above might work. We have some hours to do the conversion at launch.

Answer (score 1):

The risk is two processes selecting the MAX(order_number) before one of them inserts the new order.  A safer way is to do it in one step:

```
INSERT INTO order_table
(order_number, /* other fields */)
VALUES
( (SELECT MAX(order_number)+1 FROM order_table ) order_number,
  /* other values */
)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion but when one form is saved MULTIPLE orders may be created. So the logic is really (I should have explained better), to first select the MAX, and then if you are creating 3 orders you do 3 inserts with MAX+1,MAX+2,MAX+3.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with G_M; use an Identity field.  When you add your record, just

```
INSERT INTO order_table (/* other fields */)
VALUES (/* other fields */) ; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

The return value from [Scope Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) will be your order number.